# Is there a way to use JavaScript files when offline? (HTML/JADE/JS/OFFLINE)

Tags: javascript, html, url, offline

I have an app that requires a handful of scripts; however, there will not be an internet connection for the app to use (most of the time), is there anyway that I can change something like this:

```
script(type='text/javascript', charset='utf8', src='http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.8.2.min.js')
```

so that the code included in the URL will still be reachable from the app even without an internet connection? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, download the file and use it's path rather than the URL.

Comment: What is that code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, just download it and include in this way:

```
<script src="path to downloaded file"></script>
```

For example, if I download **jquery.js** in js folder, I should use:

```
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
```

Comment: Instead of downloading the files, you can cache them using a [service worker](https://css-tricks.com/serviceworker-for-offline/) to make the app work offline.

Answer (score 2):

There is standard trick how to load scripts from local path when online resource is not available.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">window.jQuery || document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/lib/jquery.js">\x3C/script>');</script>
```

The second script writes script tag if the first one fails to load jQuery object.